# showing status in prolog

Tags: prolog

i want to show status  like
status([[1,1][2,2],[5,5]])
$????
?$???
?????
????$

status([])
?????
?????
?????
?????
?????

can you understand? 
it's 5x5 size. but not fixed. size can be anything 10x10,6x6,7x7....
how can i do this? i am new with prolog.
actually, i want make minesweeper. i am new with prolog

Answer (score 0):

kinda tricky to change the piece on the board.

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).

status([[1,2], [3,2]]).

board([
    [a, a, a, a, a],
    [a, a, a, a, a],
    [a, a, a, a, a],
    [a, a, a, a, a],
    [a, a, a, a, a]
    ]).

get_coords([X|Y], Coord_X, Coord_Y) :-
    Coord_X is X,
    Coord_Y is Y.

write_matrix :-
    status(Positions),
    board(Board),
    print_matrix(Board, Positions).

print_matrix(Board, []).
print_matrix(Board, [Position | Next_positions]):-
    get_coords(Position, X, Y),
    set_piece(Board, X, Y, b, New_board),
    display_columns(New_board, 0),
    print_matrix(New_board, Next_positions).

display_columns([Row | Next_rows], Indexy) :-
    Indexy2 is Indexy + 1,
    Indexy2 =< 5, %max columns
    display_rows(Row, 0, Indexy2),
    display_columns(Next_rows, Indexy2).
display_columns(_, 5):-
    nl. %finished columns

display_rows([Spot | Next_spots], Indexx, Indexy) :-
    Indexx2 is Indexx + 1,
    Indexx2 =< 5, %max rows
    (
        (Spot = b, write('$'));
        (Spot = a, write('?'))
    ),  
    display_rows(Next_spots, Indexx2, Indexy).
display_rows(_, 5, _) :-
    write(' '). %finished rows

/* Change a piece of the Board, remaking it row by row */
/* If 'Y' is invalid, the same list will be returned */
set_piece([Row | Other_rows], X, Y, New_piece, [Row | Other_new_rows]) :-
    Y =\= 1,
    Next_Y is Y - 1,
    set_piece(Other_rows, X, Next_Y, New_piece, Other_new_rows).
set_piece([Row | Other_rows], X, 1, New_piece, [New_row | Other_new_rows]) :-
    set_cell(X, New_piece, Row, New_row),
    set_piece(Other_rows, X, 0, New_piece, Other_new_rows).
set_piece([], _X, _Y, _New_piece, []).

/* Change a piece of the Row, remaking it cell by cell */
/* If 'X' is invalid, the same list will be returned */
set_cell(X, New_piece, [Piece | Rest_row], [Piece | Rest_new_row]) :-
    X =\= 1,
    Next_X is X - 1,
    set_cell(Next_X, New_piece, Rest_row, Rest_new_row).
set_cell(1, New_piece, [_Piece | Rest_row], [New_piece | Rest_new_row]) :-
    set_cell(0, New_piece, Rest_row, Rest_new_row).
set_cell(_X, _New_piece, [], []).
```